# How to make shortcut of first letters of any text?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I need to write a function that returns the first letters (and make it uppercase) of any text like:

```
shortened = shorten("Don't repeat yourself")
print(shortened)
```

Expected output:

```
DRY
```

and:

```
shortened = shorten("All terrain armoured transport")
print(shortened)
```

Expected output:

```
ATAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension and join

```
shortened = "".join([x[0] for x in text.title().split(' ') if x])
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regex you can match all characters except the first letter of each word, replace them with an empty string to remove them, then capitalize the resulting string:

```
import re

def shorten(sentence):
    return re.sub(r"\B[\S]+\s*","",sentence).upper()

print(shorten("Don't repeat yourself"))
```

Output:

```
DRY
```

Answer (score -1):

```
text = 'this is a test'
output = ''.join(char[0] for char in text.title().split(' '))
print(output)
```

> TIAT

Let me explain how this works.

My first step is to capitalize the first letter of each work

```
text.title()
```

Now I want to be able to separate each word by the space in between, this will become a list

```
text.title()split(' ')
```

With that I'd end up with `'This','Is','A','Test'` so now I obviously only want the first character of each word in the list

for word in text.title()split(' '):
    print(word[0]) # T I A T

Now I can lump all that into something called list comprehension

```
output = [char[0] for char in text.title().split(' ')]
# ['T','I','A','T']
```

I can use `''.join()` to combine them together, I don't need the [] brackets anymore because it doesn't need to be a list

```
output = ''.join(char[0] for char in text.title().split(' ')
```